# Merge Gitlab Runner into existing branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm right now on a stage of automating some parts of our code. The idea is simple, with every commit in our gitlab the script takes Excel from given directory and divides it's worksheets into individual Excel files and saves them into another directory. The problem right now is that I want to merge those files into our branch from Gitlab Runner. I tried editing gitlab-ci file, but I can't get it to work. I get this error:

```
The request URL returned error: 403
```

I tried adding personal token and then using it for pushing like this:

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone
build-job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - data_dict
  script:
    - echo "Hello!"
    - ls
    - python3 -V
    - pip3 list
 
test-job1:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - data_dict
  script:
    - python3 Experiments/ConfAutomation.py
 
test-job2:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - data_dict
  script:
    - git show-ref
    - git remote -v
    - echo "$RUNNER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    - echo "Print runner branch name"
    - git config user.email "user@mail.com"
    - git config user.name "name"
    # - git remote set-url --push origin https://gitlab-ci:"$RUNNER_ACCESS_TOKEN"@gitlab/dir.git
    - git add .
    - git commit --allow-empty -m "Files from runner to branch"
    - git push origin https://gitlab-ci:"$RUNNER_ACCESS_TOKEN"@gitlab/dir.git <branch-name>
 
deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - data_dict
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something."
```

I tried some stuff but can't seem to get it to work. Maybe you had similiar problem or you have some ideas ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{$RUNNER_ACCESS_TOKEN}` without double quotes.

Comment: I still get the 403 Error. To be more specific I get "logname: no login name".